# Python - Merge CSV Files, Adding Additional Columns Based on File Name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filenames

I'm trying to merge multiple csv files within a shared folder. In addition to merging the files, I'd like to add two additional columns that identifies the data based on a portfolio code in the file name and a file date.

Currently I have the following code, which successfully merges the files:

```
import os, glob import pandas as pd
 
path = "C:\\mydirectory"
 
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "Mnthly_*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
df_merged.to_csv( "merged.csv")
 
pd.read_csv("merged.csv")
```

How can I go about adding in some kind of loop or portion within the code to include the additional columns?

Input: 'Mnthly_1_XXX'

|    DATE  -----  |  Col_1 --  |  Col_2  ---- | 
+========+======+========+ 
| 9/30/2020  | 410900 | 44991418 | 
+------------+------------+--------------+ 
| 10/31/2020 | 44936 | 48560570 | 
+------------+------------+--------------+

Output: 
|    DATE ---   |  Col_1 ----  |  Col_2 ---  | Indicator |   Date1 --  |   Date2-----   | 
+=======+=======+========+=====+========+========+ 
| 9/30/2020  | 410900 | 44991418 | XXXX      | 10/5/2020 | 10/6/2020 | 
+------------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------+--------------+ 
| 10/31/2020 | 44936 | 48560570 | XXXX      | 10/5/2020 | 10/6/2020 | 
+------------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------+--------------+

Comment: Could you provide any input example and what you expect to be returned as output?

Comment: @Keredu I edited my question to include simple examples, hopefully that helps thanks